# How to do a minus operation in bash with unknown variable type

Tags: bash

I have a semver version as a string and I want to take the patch version and do math on it. But I just can't figure this out.

This is what I have tried:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

version="appVersion=1.3.15"
version=${version##*=} # "1.3.15"
semver=( ${version//./ } ) # ["1", "3", "15"]
patch="${semver[2]}" # "15"

# So far so good.
echo $patch # 15

# This fails. I have no clue how to get the patch variable to be of the correct type
previous=${patch - 1}
echo $previous
```

Comment: Bash doesn't really have types; everything is a string, but strings might be evaluated in an arithmetic *context*: `$((...))`, or the index field when accessing an array are examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arithmetic operations in bash, you need to use Double Parentheses. Please, check this [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) section of bash manual

So your code should be:

```
previous=$((patch-1))
```

Or as [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) well suggested in a comment:

```
((previous = patch - 1))
```

Output:

```
root@:~# bash test.sh
15
14
```

Comment: Notice that within `$((...))`, you don't need the `$` to expand variables, so this could be `previous=$((patch - 1))`. As a Bashism, you could put the entire expression into `((...))`, making it even more convenient to write: `((previous = patch - 1))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You are completely right. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have been trying out a bunch of different stuff and just couldn't figure it out 